# Error: esri generateToken "GWM_0005"

Tags: python, arcgis-online

I'm getting the following error from Esri while trying to generate a token.

> Code: 405
> message_code: GWM_0005 message: 'Method not supported'

This used to work a month ago. Here's the python code:

```
def generateToken(username, password, portalUrl):
    '''Retrieves a token to be used with API requests.'''
    parameters = {'username': username,
                  'password': password,
                  'client': 'referer',
                  'referer': portalUrl,
                  'expiration': 60, # token life in minutes
                  'f': 'json'}
    url = '{}/sharing/rest/generateToken'.format(portalUrl)
    print("URL:" + url)
    response = requests.post(url, data=parameters)
    return response.json()
```

with the `url` as: [https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/generateToken?username='username'&password='password'&referer=https://www.arcgis.com&f=json](https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/generateToken?username=%27username%27&password=%27password%27&referer=https://www.arcgis.com&f=json)

Comment: If you're doing a POST, the parameters should just be URL-encoded in the POST data payload, not in the URL.

Comment: I just put in the url as an example of the data for the post. Can't get either to work

Answer (score 0):

I recently changed the password to include a special character in the password that required the password to be encapsulated in single quotes.